# How do I force my batch file to hide the cmd window and say "yes"?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Okay so I am trying to make a simple BAT file that deletes files in multiple folders. Now this is what I have so far. I would like it so it deletes all files and folders in the Temp directory but not folders in the data directory... I would also like it to say yes to the prompts. How do I do this???

```
@ECHO OFF
DEL "C:\ProgramData\TVersity\Media Server\data\*.*" 
DEL "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp\*.*"
```

I am planning on adding in more directories into this BAT file so please if you can respond with "how to commands"... Because I would like to know how to specify whether to delete all folders and files or just files.

Also how to automate the "yes" to all prompts.

Comment: If you want to hide the cmd window, you should be using something other than a batch file (or at least, using a shell script that invokes the batch file, because you can hide the cmd prompt using a shell script, but not once the batch file is already running). 
DEL without a prompt is just a matter of using the appropriate flag, which you can google trivially. :p
Also, I'm not sure this is really a question for SO.

Comment: The solution should be an **answer**, not a part of the **question**. Also when it is your own solution. Also, there is no need to change the question title. Just mark the chosen answer as correct.

Comment: Okay but I want others who have this issue to know the correct solution because mine was a combination of 2 or 3 answers... So I am going to post the solution here in the comments if it is alright? SOLUTION BELOW:

Comment: `@echo off
:: The lines containing two colons are comments and have no effect on the batch file itself
::
:: The command following the colon deletes files only and no subdirectory files or folders: echo Y | del "c:\somedirectory\*.*" 
:: The command following the colon deletes all files but not folders (even in subdirectories): del /s /q c:\somedirectory\*.*
:: The command following the colon deletes all files/folders in the directory specified: rd /s /q "c:\somedirectory\"
::
echo Y | del "C:\ProgramData\TVersity\Media Server\data\*.*" 
rd /s /q "C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Temp"
exit`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
del /s /q c:\somedirectory\*.*
```

should take care of deleting all files recursively without deleting the directories, in "quiet" mode, which doesn't give you the prompt.

To delete an entire directory and all of its files and subdirectories, you can use `rd` with the same flags:

```
rd /s /q c:\somedirectory
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771049.aspx

Comment: Thank you! I will post my completed script above using a combination of the answers!

Answer (score 3):

You can find out about the options available in the `del` command by typing `del /?`.

```
DEL [/P] [/F] [/S] [/Q] [/A[[:]attributes]] names
ERASE [/P] [/F] [/S] [/Q] [/A[[:]attributes]] names

  names         Specifies a list of one or more files or directories.
                Wildcards may be used to delete multiple files. If a
                directory is specified, all files within the directory
                will be deleted.

  /P            Prompts for confirmation before deleting each file.
  /F            Force deleting of read-only files.
  /S            Delete specified files from all subdirectories.
  /Q            Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to delete on global wildcard
  /A            Selects files to delete based on attributes
  attributes    R  Read-only files            S  System files
                H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archiving
                I  Not content indexed Files  L  Reparse Points
                -  Prefix meaning not
```

In your case, you want

```
DEL /Q "C:\ProgramData\TVersity\Media Server\data\*.*" 
DEL /Q "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp\*.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

To exit your script you need to add "exit" at the end.

To automatically press Y you can echo the character 'Y' and pipe it into your command.

For example:

```
@ECHO OFF
echo Y | DEL "C:\ProgramData\TVersity\Media Server\data\*.*" 
echo Y | DEL "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp\*.*"
exit
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to minimize the command prompt window:

```
nircmd win min title "Command Prompt"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
start /min "" ".\batchfile.bat"
```

will start your batch file minimized from another batch file.